# Node.js/pipe. Как сразу записать файлы в zip-архив через pipe и потоки?

Tags: node.js, потоки-данных, zip, pipes, archive

Делаю запросы на получение файлов модулем request.

А как сделать чтобы каждый результат запроса (файл) записывался в zip архив сразу, используя потоки и каналы?

(Чтобы, без временного сохранения в файл на диск, добавления в архив и удаления потом).

Надо Что то типа такого: rq.pipe(gzip).pipe(wstream);

```
function downloadImage(url, idx, callback){
  var dst = __dirname + "/uploads/"+req.body.Id+".gz";
  var wstream = fs.createWriteStream(dst);
  var gzip = zlib.createGzip();

  var rq = request(url);

  rq.on('error', function (err) {
if (err.code === 'ETIMEDOUT') {
console.log("ERRORR!!");
rq.end();
callback(err.code);
}});

  wstream.on("finish", function() {
          console.log(".on(finish " + idx + " " + dst);
          rq.end();
        callback(dst);
    })

  rq.pipe(gzip).pipe(wstream);
}
```

Но в этом моем коде, если файлов много , они запишутся склеившись.. А мне нужно чтобы по нормальному.. каждый файл пишется отдельно, все в один архив.

Как сделать такое? 
Может другие есть модули вместо zlib?

Comment: Для начала, вам надо изменить формат архива. Архивы формата gzip могут содержать только 1 файл.

Comment: да это не сутьважно.. Модуль хоть какой другой можно бы использовать..  Просто не могу понять как сразу записать в архив этот поток из url. Я пробовал var archiver = require('archiver'); но там тоже не понятно: archive.append делаю и чето стоит все - ниче не пишет.. Хер пойми там..

Comment: Нет, это как раз важно.

Comment: Да неее.. Ну в этом модуле var archiver = require('archiver'); задан формат архива zip..Все норм пишется в файлы..  но Меня больше интересует "КАК сразу записать в zip-архив через pipe и потоки.." Не из файла на диске прочитать и добавить, а сразу результат ответа..напрямую перенаправить в архив. КАК?

Comment: @LS2010 Посмотрите [node-zip-stream](https://github.com/archiverjs/node-zip-stream)